# Javascript closure scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures, dom-events

I was working today at a front-end Javascript project. I will try to keep the description of the problem and the solution as short as possible.
I had to add click handlers to the links on a page that redirect the user to other pages, so I had 2 Javascript array `arrayOfRedirectLinks` and `pageLinkElements`:

```
var arrayOfRedirectLinks, pageLinkElements;
```

Initially I wrote the `addEventHandlers` function like this:

```
var addEventHandlers = function() {
    var i, link;
    for( var i in arrayOfRedirectLinks) {
        link = arrayOfRedirectLinks[i];
        pageLinkElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = link;
        });
    }
}
```

I thought that this solution will do the job until... well until I opened the browser, clicked several links and noticed that all of them redirected me to the same link (the last link in the `arrayOfRedirectLinks`).

Finally I found that my problem was similar to the one posted here
[Javascript multiple dynamic addEventListener created in for loop - passing parameters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177757/javascript-multiple-dynamic-addeventlistener-created-in-for-loop-passing-param)

And indeed both the first and the second solution posted there worked for me

```
var addEventHandlers = function() {
    var i, link;
    for( var i in arrayOfRedirectLinks) {
        (function(link){
        link = arrayOfRedirectLinks[i];
        pageLinkElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = link;
        });
        }(link));
    }
}
```

and

```
var passLink = function(link) {
    return  function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               window.location = link;
            };
};
var addEventHandlers = function() {
    var i, link;
    for( var i in arrayOfRedirectLinks) {
        link = arrayOfRedirectLinks[i];
        pageLinkElements[i].addEventListener('click',passLink(link));
    }
}
```

Now this seems to work but I don't understand why it works.
I came with the following explanation and I would like if someone can confirm if it's correct:

1. When I declare a function in Javascript, it gets the references to the variables in the scope of the function where it was declared. ( i.e. my event handler gets a reference to the `link` variable in the `addEventHandlers` function)
2. Because the handler gets a reference to the variable `link`. When I reassign a value to the `link` variable, the value that will be used when the click handler  gets triggered will also change. So the `link` variable from the event handler is not simply copy with of the `link` with a different memory address and same value as when the function handler was added, but they both share the same memory address and therefore the same value.
3. Because of the reasons described at 2), the all the click handlers will use the redirect to the same `link`, the last `link` in the array `arrayOfRedirectLinks` because that's the last value that will get assigned to the `link` variable at the end of the `for` loop.
4. But when I pass the `link` variable as a parameter to another function, a new scope it's created and the `link` inside that scope actually shares only it's initial value with the value of the `link` parameter passed to the function. The references of the 2 `link` variables are different.
5. Because of 4), when I pass the `link` to the click handler, it will take the reference to the `link` variable in the Immediately Invoked Function Expression who itself doesn't share the same address with the `link` in the `addEventHandlers` function. Therefore each `link` from the event handler functions will be isolated from the others and will keep the value of the `arrayOfRedirectLinks[i]`

Is this correct?

Comment: TL;DR, but this looks like a really long duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), it's pretty basic stuff ?

Comment: [Yes, correct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572).

Answer (score 3):

This is the critical bit:

```
var i, link;
for( var i in arrayOfRedirectLinks) {
  link = arrayOfRedirectLinks[i];
  pageLinkElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = link;
  });
}
```

There is only ever one `link` variable here. Note that the  `addEventListener` callback function is only called when the link is clicked.

By that time, the variable `link` has its final value, which is shared by all event handler functions.

So all the links do the same thing.

Simplest solution (other than a wider refactor):

```
for(var i in arrayOfRedirectLinks) {      
  (function(i) {
    var link = arrayOfRedirectLinks[i];
    pageLinkElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location = link;
    });
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: You could pass the handler to decouple a bit: pageLinkElements[i].addEventListener('click', passLink(link));