# Adding addEventListener() in loop only works for last button

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, addeventlistener

I get an json-array from dynamodb and is adding an addEventListener() to a button while traversing it. But only the last button responds to this.

This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values) on SO and was the first hit on google so I changed the loop to use closures. But I still can't attach an addEventListener() to other than the last button.

I initially tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
    (function(j) {
        var obj = data.Items[j];

        adiv.innerHTML = adiv.innerHTML + "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'>" + obj.Event + ", " + obj.Location + "</div></div>";
        adiv.innerHTML = adiv.innerHTML + "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'>" + obj.Date + ", " + obj.Time + "</div></div>";
        adiv.innerHTML = adiv.innerHTML + "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'><button id='yay_button_" + i + "' class='button-primary'>Deltag</button></div></div>";

        var elem = document.getElementById('yay_button_' + j);
        elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert('id: ' + j);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

And then this shorter version:

```
(function(j) {
    document.getElementById('yay_button_' + j).addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('id: ' + j);
    });
}(i));
```

Another [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177757/javascript-multiple-dynamic-addeventlistener-created-in-for-loop-passing-param) I tried was to create a button using new:

```
function Button(id, number) {
    document.getElementById(id + number).addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('click: ' + id + number);
    });
}

new Button('yay_button_', i);
```

I tried both safari and chrome on el capitan without errors in the console. The buttons has the correct id when I inspect it, yay_button_0 and _1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main problem is that you redefine the HTML of `adiv` *completely* every time you iterate. This means that any event handler you had already bound to a child element of `adiv` is lost the moment you do `adviv.innerHTML = ...`. Although you assign the same HTML plus some new one, you don't assign the event handlers that were previously defined. So they are lost.

Only the event handler you assign at the last iteration is not destroyed in this way.

#### Solution

A quick solution would be to first loop to create all the HTML, and then do a separate loop to assign the event handlers:

```
// First add all the new content:
var html = adiv.innerHTML;
for (var i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
    var obj = data.Items[i];

    html += "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'>" + obj.Event + ", " + obj.Location + "</div></div>";
    html += "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'>" + obj.Date + ", " + obj.Time + "</div></div>";
    html += "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'><button id='yay_button_" + i + "' class='button-primary'>Deltag</button></div></div>";
}
adiv.innerHTML = html;

// Now bind the event handlers
// By using "let" instead of "var" the right value is retained
// in the handlers
for (let i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('yay_button_' + i);
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('id: ' + i);
    });
}
```

If your browser does not support ES2015 (for `let`), then you can use `bind`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('yay_button_' + i);
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(i) {
        alert('id: ' + i);
    }.bind(null, i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I tried this as well but without the closure. But now I did an additional loop with it and it works. Mind if I edit your post and paste the code?

Comment: I personally prefer the `let` solution than the extra closure. But you can post it as your own answer, which may interest future visitors.

Comment: Thank you. I use strict mode and the keyword let is not allowed. 'Unexpected use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode'. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Oh, well, I use strict mode too, and have no issue. I guess you are on Safari, who is not yet in line with this ES2015 syntax. I added another option using `bind()`.

Comment: It's mind blowing that if you use `var i =` in a loop all iterations get last value. But if you use `let i =` in a loop each iteration has the correct value for `i`. That said, I was passing `i` to an click listener and can confirm author's statement is true.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, the reason is that `let` has block scope, while `var` has function scope. Each  iteration of the `for` loop will have its own separate `i` variable when you use `let`.

Comment: Thank you. it solved my problem with separate loop

Answer (score 0):

With kind advise from trincot I traverse the array twice. First to produce the html and then to apply the addEventListener(). The second time I surround the call to addEventListener() with a closure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
    var obj = data.Items[i];

    adiv.innerHTML = adiv.innerHTML + "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'>" + obj.Event + ", " + obj.Location + "</div></div>";
    adiv.innerHTML = adiv.innerHTML + "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'>" + obj.Date + ", " + obj.Time + "</div></div>";
    adiv.innerHTML = adiv.innerHTML + "<div class='row'><div class='center-div six columns'><button id='yay_button_" + i + "' class='button-primary'>Deltag</button></div></div>";

}

for (var i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
    var obj = data.Items[i];
    (function(j, event) {
        document.getElementById('yay_button_' + j).addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert('id: ' + j + ', ' + event);
        });
    }(i, obj.Event));
}
```