# javascript: addEventListener in loop not working. passing same parameter to function with each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried the solutions offered in these two threads, however, none of them are working.

[Javascript multiple dynamic addEventListener created in for loop - passing parameters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177757/javascript-multiple-dynamic-addeventlistener-created-in-for-loop-passing-param)

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

So here is where I am at.

Here is my loop:

```
var eduWidths = [415.66, 116.13];

function eduResize(j,el){
            var edu = document.getElementById(el);
            console.log("j: "+j+" , el: "+ el +" , eduWidths[j]: "+eduWidths[j]); //output: "j: 1 , el: edu0 , eduWidths[j]: 116.13"

             //this does not work, j is always "1"
            $(edu).animate({width: eduWidths[j]+'px'}, 500);
        }

for(i=0; i<edus.length; i++){
    var edu = document.getElementById('edu'+i);

    edu.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
        //this works without any problem
        $(this).animate({width:'400px'}, 500);
    });

    var j=0;
    edu.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        //this does call the eduResize function, and passes j and this.id
            eduResize(j,this.id);

        });
    j++;
}
```

Despite having the correct target, the target div is always resizing using the 1 index position of eduWidths[] array on this line:

```
$(edu).animate({width: eduWidths[j]+'px'}, 500);
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="eduEvent" id="edu0" ></div>
<div class="eduEvent" id="edu1" ></div>
```

Comment: Need HTML, I'm not sure whether you have multiple elements involved or if you have just one.

Comment: Why mix jQuery and DOM?  $(".eduEvent").hover....

Comment: Use a common class man! No need to loop IDs.

Comment: You'll probably want to assign that ` var j=0;` outside your loop. It will always be 0 inside your eventlistener now (or why not use `i`)

Comment: I updated the question with the HTML. I have multiple elements involved.

Comment: So... what about the dupe did you not understand? I see you linked to it, but you didn't implement anything from it or explain how it isn't a dupe of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: I do see where you tried to create a function that accepts the index, which is explained in the dupe, but you then waited to call it until later within the event callback, which isn't what the linked question is suggesting.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. If jQuery's class selector is used with the proper hover or on("mouseenter"..., the problem goes away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an answer here that was deleted, that helped me solve the problem.

Is this the most efficient and proper way to do this?

This is what eventually got it to work:

```
var eduWidths = [415.66, 116.13];

function eduResize(j,el){
            var edu = document.getElementById(el);
            console.log("j: "+j+" , el: "+ el +" , eduWidths[j]: "+eduWidths[j]);
            $(edu).animate({width: eduWidths[j]+'px'}, 500);
        }


for(i=0; i<edus.length; i++){
var edu = document.getElementById('edu'+i);

            edu.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
                //this.style.width = "400px";
                $(this).animate({width:'400px'}, 500);
                //console.log("this.id: "+ this.id);
            });


            edu.addEventListener('mouseleave', (function iife(currentJ) {
              return function() {
                eduResize(currentJ, this.id);
              };
            })(i)); // <-- here you pass j, which will become currentJ inside the iife


 }//end loop
```

Answer (score -1):

When you add an event listener javascript actually puts it on the the side and executes it after all your other code is executed at which point your j value would be increment to edus.length.

You need to create lexical scope by using a function like this.

```
(function(index){
    edu.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    //this does call the eduResize function, and passes j and this.id
        eduResize(index,this.id);
})(j);
```

Comment: the event handler you used in your example isn't the one that is problematic.

Comment: right... but in your example, the iife is irrelevant. you aren't even using `index`

Comment: The whole thing is an X/Y problem. Using jQuery correctly will solve the issue completely

Comment: Maybe.. The problem is half the people doesn't really understand javascript's scope including myself.